# Getting error in executing Stored Proc from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am new to MSSQL Server and there's a stored proc created by some developer and all I need to is run the proc from my PHP code.
But I am getting below error
The formal parameter "@contract_id" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

Below is my code

```
        $params['contract_id'] = '00990007';
        $params['major_version'] = '1';
        $procedure_params = array(
            array(&$params['contract_id'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
            array(&$params['major_version'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
        );

        $sql = "EXEC [MTP].[Process_07a_create_a_contract_version_wrapper] @contract_id = ?, @major_version = ?";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);
        if( !$stmt ) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){
            while($res = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt)){
                // make sure all result sets are stepped through, since the output params may not be set until this happens
            }
            // Output params are now set,

        }else{
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
```

Can anyone guide me on this please?

Comment: If  you don't have access to SP code, you can see this sample script in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the type and the order of parameters, using [sys.parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Then set params using the results:

```
<?php
...
$sql = 
    "SELECT [name], [is_output]
    FROM sys.parameters
    WHERE object_id = object_id('[MTP].[Process_07a_create_a_contract_version_wrapper]')
    ORDER BY parameter_id";
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($res === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'Name: '.$row['name'].', ';
    echo 'Output: '.($row['is_output'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No');
    echo '</br>';
}
...
?>
```

Error message "The formal parameter "@contract_id" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output" can be raised when the @contract_id parameter is not output parameter. So you can try with this (using your code):

```
<?php
...
$sql = "{call [MTP].[Process_07a_create_a_contract_version_wrapper](?, ?)}";
$procedure_params = array(
    array($params['contract_id'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$params['major_version'], SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT)
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
// Output parameters are available after consuming all resultsets.
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
}
...
?>
```